# Unusual axes range for Pandas dataframe plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, axes

I'm trying to do simple plotting using the built-in `pandas.DataFrame.plot` function (I want to avoid the full-blown `pyplt` figure/axes object setup approach).  However, I get strange results when I don't specify the x-axes range parameter (`xlim`).  You would think that `plot` would pick defaults based on the max and min of the data.

(I'm using inline plotting in a Jupyter notebook with Python 2.7)

Setup code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline
n = 366
x = 10.0*np.random.randn(n)

time_series = pd.date_range("2016-01-01", "2016-12-31")
df = pd.DataFrame(data=x, index=time_series, columns=['X'])
df['y'] = 100 + 2.5*x + 5.0*np.random.randn(n)
df.describe()
```

Here is what the data looks like:

[image]

Desired code:

```
df.plot('X', 'y', style='.')
```

Here is what I get from above code:
[image]

Here is what I expect to get:

```
df.plot('X', 'y', xlim=(-35, 35), style='.')
```

[image]

Each time I run the code I get an equally-odd choice of default axis range.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. In case you didn't notice, pandas is setting the x limits to the first and last elements of X. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Ah.  Nice spot Goyo.  I've also just realized the solution: `df.plot('X', 'y', kind='scatter', style='.')`  I guess if `kind` is not specified, `plot` assumes an ordered series (i.e. sorted from smallest to largest).  Strange though.  It would be nicer if it noticed and complained...

Comment: Today, with my current versions (Python 3.9.7, Pandas 1.3.4) this is no longer an issue.